# JSONObject.toMap() implementation

Tags: java, json

I needed to convert a JSONObject to Map.

And i noticed that JSONObject has a .toMap() method...

Out of curiosity dove into the object itself and i noticed that it has a private member map, that holds the map of the JSONObject...

But when i look at the toMap() method i see they actually creating a new Map instance and iterating over the entire JSONObject, while they already have a private member?

So they already did the work when constructing the JSONObject, but when toMap() is called they do it again?

Why toMap() implementation isnt simply

```
new HashMap(this.map);
```

?

from JSONObject source code:

```
 /**
     * The map where the JSONObject's properties are kept.
     */
    private final Map<String, Object> map;
```

The private member almost every get method is questioning

```
/**
     * Put a key/value pair in the JSONObject. If the value is null, then the
     * key will be removed from the JSONObject if it is present.
     *
     * @param key
     *            A key string.
     * @param value
     *            An object which is the value. It should be of one of these
     *            types: Boolean, Double, Integer, JSONArray, JSONObject, Long,
     *            String, or the JSONObject.NULL object.
     * @return this.
     * @throws JSONException
     *             If the value is non-finite number or if the key is null.
     */
    public JSONObject put(String key, Object value) throws JSONException {
        if (key == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Null key.");
        }
        if (value != null) {
            testValidity(value);
            this.map.put(key, value);
        } else {
            this.remove(key);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

put method is called in every constructor scenario to populate the private map member

```
 /**
     * Returns a java.util.Map containing all of the entries in this object.
     * If an entry in the object is a JSONArray or JSONObject it will also
     * be converted.
     * <p>
     * Warning: This method assumes that the data structure is acyclical.
     *
     * @return a java.util.Map containing the entries of this object
     */
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : this.entrySet()) {
            Object value;
            if (entry.getValue() == null || NULL.equals(entry.getValue())) {
                value = null;
            } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = ((JSONObject) entry.getValue()).toMap();
            } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = ((JSONArray) entry.getValue()).toList();
            } else {
                value = entry.getValue();
            }
            results.put(entry.getKey(), value);
        }
        return results;
    }
```

toMap creates a new HashMap and literary repeats the constructor process

I feel they just use a new instance for nothing...

Am I missing something?

EDIT: so after reading the comments I can accept the new instance cause we dont want the reference to be changed.
Still, why isnt the implementation then is a simple

```
return new HashMap(this.map);
```

Why iterating over the JSONObject again?

Comment: If they returned the private field, you would be able to manipulate the elements directly(thus changing the JSONObject completely without noticing at first). By creating a copy of the map, you avoid this problem.

Comment: Ok, i agree with creating a new instance then, but why not just return new HashMap(this.map);
why go through the process again?

Comment: i think it's the same reason, nested objects wouldn't be protected against manipulations when you return new HashMap(this.map)

Comment: Exactly what @taygetos said, you would not do a deep copy of the object

Comment: Exactly what @vc73 said :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why toMap() implementation isnt simply
>
> new HashMap(this.map);

Because that would be only a shallow copy of whole object graph so it would contain only copied "current" level.

If you take closer look, you will notice that `toMap` is calling `toMap` on every child object, creating deep copy.